# SQL Set date where postcode is the same

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I currently some code which sets a date based on the row number.  I would like to use the postcode to set the so where the postcode is the same it uses the first date in Jan when it gets to the 30th Jan it loops back to using the first for the next group of postcodes.

The data should look like this:

```
CardNumber | PostCode | SchedServiceStart
34198 | GL53 | 01/01/2014
34199 | GL53 | 01/01/2014
35172 | GU4 | 02/01/2014
38764 | GU4 | 02/01/2014
83412 | GU4 | 02/01/2014
28171 | PL1 | 03/01/2014
28170 | PL1 | 03/01/2014
```

Here is the code im using currently to set the date by row number:

```
WITH CTE as 
(SELECT CardNumber,
        SchedServiceStart,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CardNumber) as rn    
  FROM tblContractSite
  INNER JOIN tblContract ON tblContractSite.ContractRef = tblContract.ContractID
  WHERE tblContractSite.SiteServiceTypeRef = 1 )

UPDATE CTE 
 SET SchedServiceStart
       =CAST('01/01/2014' as Datetime)+(rn-1)%30 -- 30 day period in jan from the 1st
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your query just replace:

```
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CardNumber) as rn
```

with [DENSE_RANK()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx):

```
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY POSTCODE) as rn
```

In this case you will get the same incremented `rn` for each group based on `POSTCODE`